# Angular2 Material Snackbar - How to include html

Tags: angular, angular-material

How do I include html in my message to Angular 2 material's snackBar? E.g. if I want to send some styling like  or an icon etc?

Comment: What about using `openFromComponent()` from API provided by `MatSnackBar`?

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'snack-bar-component-example',
  templateUrl: 'snack-bar-component-example.html',
})
export class SnackBarComponentExample {
  constructor(public snackBar: MatSnackBar) {}

  openSnackBar() {
    this.snackBar.openFromComponent(PizzaPartyComponent, {
      duration: 500,
    });
  }
}
```

Or check [Angular example](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/examples)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do that. mat-snackbar accepts a MatSnackBarConfig, where you can configure some things, see : https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/api#additional_classes

Maybe you should write your own custom snackbar if you need a high degree of customization.

Edit : as kav said, you can use openFromComponent(), try stackblitz provided in material.angular.io

Answer (score 0):

In my project I wanted to add something of an info icon to the snackbar. I was able to acheive it using content in css

```
  .mat-snack-bar-container {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255)!important;
    background-color: grey!important;
    opacity:0.9;
    span:before {
      content: '\26A0 ';
    }
 }
```

[image: 1]

For the content codes, i found this link to be helpful : https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/symbols/